# Generic Message Queue Interface

Tags: design-patterns, go

I'm trying to implement an Interface for a Message Queue. This interface should allow different implementations of queues to be implemented etc AWS SQS, Azure Queue Service.

So lets say that I have an interface for the Message Queue:

```
type Queue interface {
   AddMessageToQueue(msg QueueMessage)
}
```

I also have an interface for the message:

```
type QueueMessage interface {
   ToSQSFormat() ...
   ToAzureFormat() ...
   ...
}
```

The QueueMessage interface will allow the implementation of the Queue to convert it into the required format.

Is this the proper way to achieve this? Is the QueueMessage interface violating interface segregation principle as the queue implementation will have access to all the "To...Format" methods in addition to the one it requires?

Comment: You could introduce converters `SQSMessageConverter`, `AzureMessageConverter` which take a `QueueMessage` and produce concrete `SQSMessage`, `AzureMessage` objects. This way, the `QueueMessage` does not need to know anything about the concrete formats. However, this only works if you can access the `QueueMessage` data from its interface without knowing the concrete implementation.

Comment: This could be achieved by adding a single `ToMyAwesomeFormat()` method which converts the message into a specific format. The converters then take `MyAwesomeFormat` as input and produce concrete `SQSMessage`, `AzureMessage` objects.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a strong candidate for the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You want to aim at designing flexible and reusable code as much as possible and avoid cluttering your interface with specific methods for each format type. Here's how I'd approach it:

1. Expect each queue message to have a `Format()` method that returns a `[]byte`

```
type QueueMessage interface {
    Format() []byte
}
```

2. Define each type separately and let it (implicitly) implement the `QueueMessage` interface

```
type SQSFormat struct {
    ID string
    Payload string
    At time.Time
}

func (s SQSFormat) Format() []byte {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", s))
}

type AzureFormat struct {
    Channel string
    Payload string
}

func (a AzureFormat) Format() []byte {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", a))
}
```

3. Now you can process each message in the queue and calling `Format()` will format the message based on the specific concrete type.

```
type Queue interface {
    AddMessageToQueue(msg QueueMessage)
    ProcessMessages()
}

type MessageQueue struct{
    Messages []QueueMessage
}

func (m *MessageQueue) AddMessageToQueue(msg QueueMessage) {
    if m.Messages == nil {
        m.Messages = []QueueMessage{}
    }
    m.Messages = append(m.Messages, msg)
}

func (m *MessageQueue) ProcessMessages() {
    for _, msg := range m.Messages {
        fmt.Println(string(msg.Format())) // <- will print the formatted message based on the concrete type specified
    }
}

func main() {
    var mq Queue = &MessageQueue{}
    var SQSMsg = SQSFormat{
        ID: "id",
        Payload: "something happened",
        At: time.Now(),
    }
    mq.AddMessageToQueue(SQSMsg)

    var azureMsg = AzureFormat{
        Channel: "channel",
        Payload: "something happened",
    }
    mq.AddMessageToQueue(azureMsg)

    mq.ProcessMessages()
}
```

A working example: https://play.golang.org/p/4Enql_wnd4o

Hope this helps, let me know if you need some clarification.